# UK Tier 2 visa processing time for applications submitted in Bhutan

Tags: visas, application-status

we have applied tier 2 visa for UK from our UK agent and still under process, so i just want to know how long it will take time to process after completion of documents.

Comment: You applied for a UK visa or for a Bhutan visa?

Comment: @GayotFow The title says for Bhutan, the body says for UK. That's why I asked for clarifications and voted to close as unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you used the VFS Centre in Thimphu and paid for standard processing...

You can open [Visa Application Processing Times](https://visa-processingtimes.homeoffice.gov.uk/y) and select "Unknown/Unknown" for Bhutan, and then select "Show All" and then "Other Non-Settlement"...

[image]

...and see that the historical average is 5 days. This estimate is not adjusted to account for seasonal influences and may take up to 90 days. For working purposes you can assume somewhere between 5 and 15 days to process a T2 application submitted in Bhutan.

Comment: I'll follow yes: I'll try to snatch that 500 rep bounty from anyone else here on TSE. :D Enough chit-chat, I'll delete the comments.